# Is living in Thailand on a dependant visa termed as living in that country or visiting?

Tags: visas, canada, tourist-visas, residency

I want to apply for a Canada tourist visa, and we have a question under previous travel that asks

> Since the age of 18 or during the past 5 years, whichever is most recent, have you travelled to any other country or territory other than the country or territory of citizenship or residence?

I had a Non-Imm "O" dependant visa while I was in Thailand. It also conflicts with another question of another form that asks about any other place I might have lived for more than 6 months.

What should I enter in such a case?

1. Is Thailand considered as my residential country? I do not have any documents under my name.
2. Should I record visits to Thailand as visits to the place, or would it mean that it is my country of residence and so I should not include in the travel history?

Does anyone know how I should fill in the forms to avoid rejection?

Note to all who think that I am asking this to avoid mentioning it on my application:

1. I am not willing to hide anything at all since I am aware of the consequences. Otherwise I would not be worried about getting confused in the first place between the two questions. **It is the form itself that mentions clearly not to write down any travel history to and from the country of residence/citizenship**

Comment: How long did you stay in Thailand? Why did you stay in Thailand? The `O` literally stands for *'other'*, as-in *'purposes other than those covered by the other visas'*.

Comment: Maybe add Thailand as place you have visited (with annotation that you lived there) and also add it to places where you have lived with the dates when you lived?

Comment: If you keep claiming that you are not trying to hide anything, then why do you ALSO keep arguing against an answer that explains that you _shouldn't_ hide anything and why? What is your game at all here? Are you just deliberately trolling to waste as much volunteer time as you possibly can?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would interpret it as "other than the country/countries you're a citizen or resident of *now*". That seems to make sense because you're declaring your current residence and citizenship elsewhere in the application.

In general, if your find questions on a visa form ambiguous, aim to err in the direction of *disclosing* information. If you keep something secret that they think you should have disclosed (and you're found out), you'll be in big trouble for years to come. On the other hand, if you give some information in two different places on the form, they will just shrug and move on.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/93461/discussion-on-answer-by-henning-makholm-is-living-in-thailand-on-a-dependant-vis).